# Win32 Api Serial Port setting shake?

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to set up the com port the same way a vendor's utility app does.
The following is what the utility app sets:

```
0.00000200  PtiDReaderSetup IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW   
Serial1 SUCCESS Shake:80000040 
Replace:80000000 
XonLimit:2048 
XoffLimit:512
```

`XonLimit` and `Xofflimit` aren't a problem. I can set them easily. It's the shake and replace  that I can't seem to figure out. From what I can tell, its values are represented by the combination of other settings.

I can't seem to find any reference material pertaining to this.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN contains a listing of the file [Ntddser.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308432.aspx).

> The header file ntddser.h lists serial port driver interfaces, structures and device control codes

Serach for `typedef struct _SERIAL_HANDFLOW` to get to the relevant part. I'm sorry, but I can't tell you anything about the exact meaning of these defines, but Google might be your friend.

Comment: Also got some more info at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-172883.html